# How to determine if a component\file, in an InstallShield .ism file, needs to be scanned?

Tags: dependencies, installshield

InstallShield 2021 R2, Basic MSI project.

This project was created years ago, and components were added to it by individuals that really don't know InstallShield, and the developers that created the exe's, dll's, ocx's, etc., files are no longer around.  I am supporting it now.

The project setting is set so that for any created component, '.Net Scan at Build' is set to 'Dependencies and Properties...[image: Net Settings]

The build of the project, because of all the dependency scans, takes longer than it should, and I am trying to reduce this build time.  I am looking for a way to determine if a dependency scan is necessary for every component. I am not a coder (and like I said above, those developers are no longer around), so how can I determine if a file should have a dependency scan.  Is there a tool\script\whatever, that I can used to scan all the files in a folder (or one file at a time), that will tell me if it is .Net, and if it needs a scan to be done in the installer project?